# What is the resistivity of n- and p-type silicon at operating temperatures?

Tags: resistance, materials, resistivity, silicon

Searching around for the resistivity of p and n silicon, so far I can only find data such as this:

[image]

[image source](https://www.aplusphysics.com/courses/honors/microe/)

Notice it says "Room Temperature Silicon". What I want to know is the resistivity **at operating temperatures.** My computer temperature probe usually indicates 40 to 65 C so that is what I'm taking as operating temperatures.

I would also like to note that the resistivity indicated here is very high in comparison to copper. 1 Ohm-cm is equal to 0.01 Ohm-m. Copper is more like 1.7 10^-8 Ohm-m. That is six orders of magnitude better, which leads me to believe that the doped silicon will get 1 million times hotter (**Edit:** power dissipation, not hotter) than copper for any given current. Is that really true? Hard to believe.

Anyway, what is the resistivity at operating temperatures? I'd like to see how steep or shallow is the coefficient of temperature for resistivity (and if it's positive or negative).

Comment: Try searching for electrical conductivity instead. 1 million times more power dissipated doesn't meant 1 million times hotter.

Comment: The voltages are fixed or constrained and relatively low. The power dissipation for a given geometry and voltage is inversely proportional to the resistivity. If it's Rds(on) you're looking at, it might increase by 50% from room temperature to a (high) operating temperature.